# TypeError: $.post(...).success is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me with my code below.. In Firefox developer tool I am getting error message: :TypeError: $.post(...).success is not a function

All variables are submitted from form page..

Any advice and suggestions will be appreciated ...

Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#post-comment-btn').click(function(){

        var _comment = $('#comment-post-text').val();
        var _userId = $('#userId').val();
        var _userName = $('#userName').val();

        if(_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null) {

            $.post("ajax/comment_insert.php",

                {
                    task : "comment_insert",
                    userId : _userId,
                    comment: _comment,


                }
                ).success(
                    function(data)
                {
                    console.log("ResponseText:" + data);
                }

                );


            console.log(_comment + " Username: " + _userName + " User Id: " + _userId);

        } else {

            console.log("The text area is empty..");

        }

        $('#comment-post-text').val("");


    });

});
```

Comment: i mean... that function hasn't existed for a loooong time. Deprecated forever, and removed in 3.0 http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 16):

There is no `$.post().success` method anymore, the function returns a promise, and can be used with `done`, `fail`, `always`, `then` etc, but not `success`

```
$.post("ajax/comment_insert.php", {
    task    : "comment_insert",
    userId  : _userId,
    comment : _comment,
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("ResponseText:" + data);
});
```

The documentation for all ajax methods in jQuery now clearly states that

> The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callback
>   methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`,
>   `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.